# using Case in django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display the value A,B,C or D as per the total of a blogger. But I am getting the error - Cannot resolve keyword 'total' into field.Can someone suggest the correct way of doing it. Thanks

models.py

```
class Blog(models.Model):

     author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='blogs') 
     likes  = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='blog_likes')
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

     def total_likes_received(user):
          return user.blogs.aggregate(total_likes=Count('likes'))['total_likes'] or 0

     @property
     def total(self):
         return count(self.author.title) + count(self.author.likes)
```

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return (Blog.objects.filter(date__lte=timezone.now())
                                    .order_by('date')
                                    .annotate(
                name=Case(
                      When(total__gt=0,total__lte=11, then=Value('B')),
                      When(total__gt=10,total__lte=21, then=Value('C')),
                      When(total__gt=20,total__lte=31, then=Value('D')),
                      default=Value('A'),
                      output_field=CharField(),
                         ),
                                              ).values_list('name')
            )
```

Comment: a property method can't act as a field, and will not be possible to filter with it in django ORM

Comment: I want to add total (sum of two fields) as a field to my model so that I can use it further. How can I do that ?

Comment: **Bad luck!** To filter based on property method, you have to load the object into Python to evaluate the property. **Django filters operate at the database level**, generating SQL.

Comment: ok. Can you tell me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Ok let me give it a try, but before that, can you clear your code, `self.author.title` refers to what? because `self` is the instance, and then you do `self.author` means the author field which is Foreign Key to User, I don't understand, also `self.author.likes`.... Does User have these fields `title`,`likes`?

Comment: The model posted is no way affiliated to Post, please update and post the full code.. are you aware that `self.author.title` means `self` = the current instance models *(blog instance)* plus a lookup to attribute `author` which is `User` instance since **author** is a foreign key to **User**, and then title which is supposed to be a `field` from **User** this is where I get confused

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174309/discussion-between-user-and-lemayzeur).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You Must also Using Django [**`F()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) and **`Count()`** annotate functions...
Try Below code:

```
Blog.objects.annotate(
    author_titles=Count('author__title'),
    author_likes=Count('author__likes')
).annotate(
    total=F('author_titles') + F('author_likes')
).annotate(
    name=Case(
        When(total__gt=0,total__lt=11, then=Value('B')),
        When(total__gt=10,total__lt=21, then=Value('C')),
        When(total__gt=20,total__lt=31, then=Value('D')),
        default=Value('A'),
        output_field=CharField(),
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you suggest me to get the total count of blogs by a user. I am trying to get the sum of likes and total blogs by a user in total. But I am getting the count of blogs wrong